# Can Openpyxl read array formulae from excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am creating a tool that reads excel formula in order to do some analysis on the functions used. I am currently using `openpyxl` to read in the formulae of an excel workbook, but I am encountering an issue where array formula are read in as an equals sign only, i.e., `=`.

The code I am using to read the formulae is:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book, data_only=False)
```

An array formula is of the form `{=SUM(LEN(B2:B11))}` or `={formula}`

It seems to be the curly braces `{` which cause the issue. Has anyone experienced this issue before, or know of a workaround (using a different library if necessary) for this issue?

Cheers,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Array formulae are **currently** (openpyxl 3.0.x) stored separately in the `ws.formula_attributes` dictionary.

The curly brackets for array formulae and data tables (coming) are GUI-only artefacts.